# Connect to Cosmos DB account using Azure Managed Service Identity

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to connect to Azure cosmos DB using MSI the same way as it is possible for Azure SQL?

That's how it works for Azure SQL Server

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.AccessToken = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
    await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

    //...
}
```

I'm not able to find anythig like this for Cosmos DB. While MSI support for it seems to be enabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not directly. Cosmos DB doesnt support Azure AD auth - hence cant use MSI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities

You can use MSI to pull Cosmos DB keys though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-cosmos-db